# Vector not defined by components in sympy

Tags: sympy

Is it possible in the Sympy vector package to initialize a vector without having to declare its components? Often when we do symbolic calculations it is not required to explicitate components.

Answer (score 1):

The Vector objects in Vector module always have three slots for components, which have to be filled with numeric or symbolic expressions. If you don't want to provide the names of components, `matrix_to_vector` can be used, passing a list of freshly created symbols to fill the slots.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, matrix_to_vector
N = CoordSys3D("N")
v = matrix_to_vector(symbols("v_1:4"), N)
```

Now `v` is a vector with components v_1, v_2, v_3.

---

In another direction, one can do linear algebra using [Matrix Expressions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html), representing vectors as matrices with one column. This conforms better to the idea of manipulating vectors without listing their components

```
from sympy import MatrixSymbol
v  = MatrixSymbol("v", 3, 1)
A = MatrixSymbol("A", 3, 3)
print(A*v)  # simply A*v 
(A*v).as_explicit()   # print out in components
```

prints

```
Matrix([
[A[0, 0]*v[0, 0] + A[0, 1]*v[1, 0] + A[0, 2]*v[2, 0]],
[A[1, 0]*v[0, 0] + A[1, 1]*v[1, 0] + A[1, 2]*v[2, 0]],
[A[2, 0]*v[0, 0] + A[2, 1]*v[1, 0] + A[2, 2]*v[2, 0]]])
```

Comment: I would like to know if it is possible to write a dot product using vector object as A*B instead of (A_1 e_1 + A_2 e_2)*(B_1 e_1 + B_2 e_2) as in the matrix expression.